# vim go to the end of jumplist

Tags: vim, jumplist, nnoremap

in vim, with

```
:jumps
```

I see the jumplist, with `G` I go to the end of jumplist.

How I can go the end of list with a map ?
I think in some like this

```
nn <leader>j :jumps<CR>G
```

but this, show the jumplist and go to the end of original file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The “more prompt” is not subject to mappings. From [`:help more-prompt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/message.txt.html#more-prompt):

> Note: The typed key is directly obtained from the terminal, it is not mapped
>   and typeahead is ignored.

You can define a mapping to reset the [`more` option](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27more%27) just before executing `:jumps` (and restore it afterwards) like this (in your `.vimrc`):

```
map <Leader>j :
            \let prevmore=&more<Bar>
            \set nomore<Bar>
            \jumps<Bar>
            \let &more=prevmore<CR>
```

When you use this `\j` mapping (Leader is backslash by default, see [`:help mapleader`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#mapleader)), Vim will display the whole jump list without any pauses until it gets to the end (effectively, you will see the last “page” of the output).

Note that `<Leader>`, and `mapleader` have nothing to do with the backslashes used above; those are [line continuations](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#line-continuation) for `:source`d files (like `.vimrc`).

Comment: nn <silent><leader>j :setl more!<bar>jumps<bar>setl more!

Comment: @juanpablo: There is no need for `setl` since `more` is a global-only option. Watch out if you ever set `nomore` outside of the mapping though — your double-toggle approach would then end up giving you the opposite of what you want for the `jumps` command (`more` set when `jumps` is run).

Answer (score 1):

Vim help documentation says the jump list is fixed to a maximum of 100 entries, and you can use a count with CTRL-I (prev) and CTRL-O (next) ... so the obvious way to "go to end" of the jumplist would be:

```
100<C-O>
```

This would perform what you're looking for.  Put it in a mapping or whatever you desire.